# leading dots in an include file

Tags: c++, c, windows

I am familiar with the concept of including a file using the include directive but what does the following statement mean, particularly the two leading dots and the backslash??

```
#include "..\CmnHdr.h"
```

Comment: In addition to the meaning described in the answers below, it means that the programmer who wrote it was a nitwit. *Finding* the header is the compiler's job; specifying the path this way binds the code to a particular directory structure.

Comment: Well.. the programmer
 who wrote it was Jeffrey Richter so I think you can take back your comment..

Comment: Even Jeffrey Richter can make mistakes.  It's still better to specify search path information as an argument to the compiler, rather than putting it into the code.

Comment: I'll eat my words iff someone shows me a solid argument for deliberately making code non-portable, or using an inferior compiler/builder. Name-dropping doesn't impress me.

Comment: @Beta: You have a point if we were talking about absolute paths.  You would never put something like `#include "C:/MyFolder/include/CmnHdr.h"` -- But I really don't see a problem with creating a directory structure for a library of code and expecting that directory structure to stay in tact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two leading dots mean the parent directory of the current directory. It's an old convention in which `.` means current directory and `..` means the parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

it's a way of specifying a file to include with relation to where the current file exists. in the case above, that tells the compiler to include the file CmnHder.h in the parent directory of the current file. you may also see just one dot, that means the current directory.